# c#, ASP, HyperLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I create a list with upload files (just .txt files),

```
blListDocs.Items.Clear();  

            string pn = Server.MapPath("../Uploads/Data");  

            string pathToWebAppRoot = Request.ApplicationPath;  
            string pathToFolder = "/Uploads/Data/";  
            string urlPath = pathToWebAppRoot + pathToFolder; 

            String[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(pn);

            for (int i = 0; i < fileList.Length - 1; i++)  
            {  
              ListItem li = new ListItem();  
              li.Text = Path.GetFileName(fileList[i]);  
              li.Value = urlPath + li.Text;  
              blListDocs.Items.Add(li);  
            }
```

Now, when I click one item link, the file's content is opening in another Web Page, but I'd like to read clicked file's content in  control

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtReadDocs" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="4"></asp:TextBox>
```

Thank You so much!!

Comment: In one of the answers you commented that you have to do this without JavaScript. Does this include server-side ASP.NET controls which automatically generate JavaScript? If this is allowed, the solution could be a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com)

```
function onLinkClick(link) {            
    $.get(link.href, '', function(data) {
        $("input[id*=txtReadDocs]").val(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to do this without javascript, just C#, it is possible ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a server side implementation link the url of your page to the same page and append a querystring parameter specifying which text file you want...then you have full access to read the text file and stuff it into your control.  Otherwise use the jQuery answer listed by @ChaosPandion